# Limiting distribution of infinite sum of weighted bernoulli?

Tags: probability, summation, random-variables, random, central-limit-theorem

Let $p_n$ be some fixed pulse, for example $p_n =e^{-n^{2}}$

We have an infinite sum
$y = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_n p_{-n}$ 
where $a_n$ are iid bernoulli random variables taking the values $+/- \sqrt{k}$ with equal probability.

Using the CLT, show this is approximately gaussian.

I'm not seeing how to correctly apply the CLT here - I can simulate the sum of many iterations in matlab and verify it looks gaussian, but I'm not sure how to show this.

Comment: What is the definition of pulse? On the other hand, what is $k$?

Comment: @sinbadh pulse is just a DSP term, in this case just think of it as something that falls off - which is why i chose the exponential.

$k$ is just some constant we can set. For example, it's fine to consider the problem with $k=1$.

Comment: Have you tried writing out $y = a_0p_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n+a_{-n})p_n$ and check the Lyapunov's CLT condition?

Comment: @BGM thanks I worked it out. Looks like its also possible with lindenbergs CLT too!